# "This model does not contain a SkinningData tag." exception

Tags: xna, blender

I've been using tutorial from wikibooks, but I'm stuck at model rendering.
( http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Creating_a_Simple_3D_Game_with_XNA/Rendering_Your_Model )
When I try to compile, I get this exception: "This model does not contain a SkinningData tag.".

What I though about, is that model wasn't exported properly, but it doesn't work after using model from their site.

I will be thankfull for any help.

Comment: Have you changed the property `Content Processor` to the `SkinnedModelProcessor`?

Comment: @NeilKnight lol this has burned me sooo many times, thanks ^^

Comment: In case if anyone didn't knew, you have to right click the fbx model and go to properties to change the above mentioned property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out!  When you import your model into VS, right click on your model, go to properties and make sure that "SkinnedModelProcessor" is set for Content Processor.

That's it!

Cheers