# NullReferenceException Error in Pipeline.Conte

Tags: c#, xna

I use the code from the "XNA 3D Primer", by M.C. Neel from Wrox. I have a problem with the code for "Chapter 8", page 31. I have the variable *robotAni* where *robotAni* is declared of type *MeshAnimationInfo* (*MeshAnimationInfo* is a class for *Pipeline.Content*).

```
    MeshAnimationInfo robotAni;
    Matrix[] robotTransforms;
```

The code for *LoadContent* is :

```
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        robot = Content.Load<Model>("Robot");

        robotAni = robot.Tag as MeshAnimationInfo;
        robotTransforms = new Matrix[robotAni.BoneTransforms.Count];
    }
```

The code in my file is absolutely identical with the code from the book. I have the following error in the last line :

*NullReferenceException was unhandeld*

and that is perfectly right as long as *robotAni*, in the line above, is null. So, could you help me how to fix this error ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As you've noticed `robot.Tag` is null.. Because of this your robotAni is null too.

If you're wondering why your tag is null pelease check [this response by Nick Gravelyn](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/468426-modeltag-is-null-xna/#entry4080620) that says:

> Are you correctly using an importer or processor that fills the Model.Tag property with something? By default (using the default model importer and processor) nothing gets put in the Tag property.

As you can find in [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697413/this-model-does-not-contain-a-skinningdata-tag-exception) you might forgot to set your `Content Processor` property to the `SkinnedModelProcessor` in your model file properties window (use properties window in visual studio).

Comment: Thank you Lukasz. I tried to set ContentProcessor as advised but I did not find SkinnedModelProcessor for ContentProceesor. (I use XNA 3.0, VC# 2008 Express)

Comment: As Kikaimaru said here (http://goo.gl/L9QQ1): `Your content project needs to have reference to pipeline extension project`. I'm not sure if those extensions are part of XNA or are third-party libraries..

Comment: Thank you again. The references were already added. I checked all the files. It is the same problem.